# Script keeps looping Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a simple script that I would like to check if there is data in column J, but it seems to keep looping and bringing up the notification...

```
function checkGaps() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Subgrade'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('J18:J'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  

  //Condition check in J18:J
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] != "") {
      Browser.msgBox('Possible duplicates found marked in RED.');
      }
    }
  }
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the loop after the first time it finds a value you can add a [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) inside the `if`:

```
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] != "") {
      Browser.msgBox('Possible duplicates found marked in RED.');
      break;
  }
}
```