# Problem with the order of IF statements Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am struggling to set up my IF statements properly, basically I want to check if there is data in column J, if empty continue on with the rest of the script, if there is data ask if the user wants to continue, and then either continue or terminate depending on their response.

Here is the start of my code:

```
function exportSg() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Subgrade'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('J18:J'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] != "") {
  
  var response = ui.alert("Gaps greater than 50 meters identified in report, unhide column J to identify. \n\n Do you want to cancel the export?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  Logger.log(response);
  
  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Export Cancelled...")}else {

SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Exporting Subgrade Report...");
```

The problem seems to be when there is no data in column J it does not continue with the export.

Anyone fancy shedding some light??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68079097/3751868) to you, you can use a [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) to stop a loop.

In your case, that means to have a break when the user clicks the YES button:

```
if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Export Cancelled...");
  break;
}
```

If you want to export even if there is no data to be used by the `for` statement, you need to move the export part to outside of it:

```
function exportSg() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Subgrade'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('J18:J'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var shouldExport = true;
  for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if ( testvalue[i] != "") {
      var response = ui.alert("Gaps greater than 50 meters identified in report, unhide column J to identify. \n\n Do you want to cancel the export?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
      Logger.log(response);
  
      if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Export Cancelled...");
        shouldExport = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (shouldExport) {
    myExportFunction();
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks mshcruz, I should have been more specific with my problem, I have edited my question, but basically the problem seems to be when there is no data in column J it does not continue with the export.

Comment: It might have to do with how you're organizing the brackets of your IFs and FORs. Are you doing the export part inside or outside the FOR? If there is no data, then the execution won't go inside the FOR, so you need to do the export outside.

Comment: yeah, quite possibly, ive tried a few variations, it either disregards the first if statement or just does nothing...

Comment: I've updated the answer with a sample that might be helpful in this case.

Comment: Thanks mshcruz, this doesnt report if there is nothing in column J which I require. Should I just add another: if ( testvalue[i] == "")

Comment: The reporting is done based on the variable "shouldExport", which is initialized as "true", meaning that it'll always export unless its value is changed inside the FOR. In the case that all cells in the J column are empty, then the value of "shouldExport" remains the same. The execution then goes out of the FOR and verifies the "shouldExport" variable, which is still true, thus the function to export is called.